# My keras model never predicts a value smaller than a specific value

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, lstm, tf.keras

I have created and trained a model to fit and predict stock market data using LSTMs and a small fully connected layer at the end. This is my model architecture:

[image: model definition]

[image: model summary]

After training my model on my data and using it on my validation set I get these predictions(the red line is the predictions and blue one is the actual values):

[image: prediction plots]

In the first section of examples the predictions seem being decent and the model is correctly predicting the values. But it seems the model cannot predict any value that is smaller than a specific value (hence, that constant line in the prediction starting around index number ~800), and is always predicting that same value.

- I want to understand what went wrong with my model and why is it behaving this way, and how to fix it. Is it because of the 'relu' activation? (my target value is min-maxed in the range [0,1], so shouldn't it still be able to predict positive values very close to 0?)

NB : The plot of predictions above is the plot of my unscaled target(min-max), and obviously the values predicted directly from my model (scaled) show the same behavior and the constant number it is predicting is **0.030465**:
[image]

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is that the output of the relu in "model_2_dense_1" is clipped to be >= 0 and perhaps 0 is being transformed by "model_2_dense_2" to >= 0.03...   Could you please try removing the activation from "model_2_dense_1" and see whether that makes any difference.

Comment: Thank you.That's what I am actually trying right now, I posted the question while I'm training a new model whose output layer is now : output =  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation=None, name="model_output")(x)

Comment: That's "model_2_dense_2" that you've modified.   I would suggest trying instead to modify "model_2_dense_1".

Comment: I intended to first try and just change the output layer's activation and if the issue wasn't resolved I would try with the earlier layers, but it seems to be enough to fix my issue.